# C++ - Haystack/Needle string check always returns false

Tags: c++

I wrote a little method to see if a string contains another string.
I have just one little problem with it though, it always returns false.

Given the haystack is a string called salaryCheck with a value of "10.1", and the needle is ".". It always returns false.

From my understanding it should return true, I first put everything into characters vectors for readability. Then I enter a loop in which I check if the first needle character matches haystack[i].
If the first needle character matches haystack[i], I proceed to enter another loop where I compare all haystack starting at haystack[i] with the full list of needle characters.

As far as I know, this should return true with my given arguments.

Here's my code:

```
bool contains(std::string& haystack, std::string needle){
    if (haystack.size() < needle.size())
        return false;

    bool returnValue = false;
    std::vector<char> haystackChars;
    std::vector<char> needleChars;

    for (char c : haystack)
        haystackChars.push_back(c);
    for (char c : needle)
        needleChars.push_back(c);

    for (int i = 0; i < haystackChars.size() && !returnValue; i++){
        if (needleChars[0] == haystackChars[i])
            for (int i2 = i; i2 < needleChars.size(); i2++){
                if (needleChars[i2] == haystackChars[i2])
                    returnValue = true;
                else{
                    returnValue = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Why are you programming your own function? Why not `string::find` or [`search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search)?

Comment: Why do you pass one string by (non-const) reference, and the other by value? Why do you copy their characters to vectors? Why are you using `for` loops to do that? And many more questions... I'd suggest you post this piece of code on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) once it's working, to get some tips on what can be improved.

Comment: This seemed like a good opportunity to learn.

Comment: have you done *any* debugging? what was the symptom?

Comment: I put them in vectors for readability, I use for loops because that seemed to be the best way to iterate through everything. I use the reference because I only want to use it with string variables. The needle however doesn't have to be a variable.

Comment: You can use `[]` indexing on `string` though. I don't think the vector adds anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
        for (int i2 = i; i2 < needleChars.size(); i2++){
```

You should loop between `0` and `needleChars.size()`, or maybe `i` and `i + needleChars.size()`. And the `if` statement below will need to be adjusted as well; the correct array index for `needle` and `haystack` is not going to be the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I looked it through multiple times but didn't notice my error. I'll close the question ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of cents, take it as you please.

```
bool contains(std::string& haystack, std::string needle){
// you only need to inspect haystack and needle, so 
bool contains(const std::string& haystack, const std::string& needle)
// is preferred. You also get convinient constructors, simplifying the 
// function call. And of course the const guarantee

// This is ok. 
    if (haystack.size() < needle.size())
        return false;
// returnValue will be unneccesary, you can leave as soon as you find the positive.
    bool returnValue = false;
// The vector does not add anything useful. std::string works fine with indexes.
    std::vector<char> haystackChars;
    std::vector<char> needleChars;

    for (char c : haystack)
        haystackChars.push_back(c);
    for (char c : needle)
        needleChars.push_back(c);

    // The algorithm is unnecessarily complex, 
    // use the string members to simplify.
    for (int i = 0; i < haystackChars.size() && !returnValue; i++){
        if (needleChars[0] == haystackChars[i])
            // This for statment can be rewritten as
            if ( haystack.substring( i, needleSize ) == needle )
                return true;
            for (int i2 = i; i2 < needleChars.size(); i2++){
                if (needleChars[i2] == haystackChars[i2])
                    returnValue = true;
                else{
                    returnValue = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
    // this becomes return false. 
    return returnValue;
}
```

So with these revisions:

```
bool contains(const std::string& haystack, const std::string& needle){
    if (haystack.size() < needle.size())
        return false;
    size_t needleSize = needle.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < haystack.size(); i++){
        if ( haystack.substr( i, needleSize ) == needle )
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As dyp notes, substr can be potentially costly, string::find to the rescue. The conditional can also be written as

```
        if ( haystack.find( needle.c_str(), i, needleSize ) == i )
                return true;
```

Or of course as suggested, if this wasn't an exercise, this would be done as

```
if ( haystack.find( needle ) != string::npos )
```

Comment: @dyp Big blunder. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Much better ;) But I think it's not necessary to use `needle.c_str()`, `string::find` has an overload that takes a `string const&`. In any case, I think the `== 0` comparison is incorrect: `find` returns a position (and index).

Comment: @dyp =) Thanks again. One of these days I'll learn to check my code.